# Problem launching an application installed using wine

Tags: wine, unity-dash

I installed an Lightshot using wine, but I cannot start the application, searching in the dash I get the following :

[image: lightshot]

Comment: What happens if you try to launch it from the WINE program?

Answer (score 0):

[WineHQ entry for Lighshot](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=14368)

Please read the above entry and understand it doesn't work well with Wine. Anything below gold is a waste of time.

Comment: What do you mean? I cannot find that statement in that website that says it doesn't work in wine

Comment: I mean what I wrote: ANYTHING with classifications other than Platinum (everything works as expected) or Gold (almost everything works as expected) is a waste of YOUR time because it won't work one way or another and you actually already know that.

Comment: what about this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=80pld6MY0-Q)

Comment: Why should I care? Haven't you opened the official Wine page about it? This is a Q&A, not a forum. If you want to discuss it take it to the Youtube comments section.